# How to display common header and footer by default in angular 2?

Tags: angular, ngroute

I have common header components and footer components. countries list are loading on homepage. whenever click on the country. page will get reloaded and displaying text `Loading...` and then header and footer displaying. but I want to display the header and footer default without waiting for full page loaded. My code here.

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
    const routes: Routes = [
      { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'home',  component: HomepageComponent,},
      { path: ':city', component: CountryDetailComponent },  
      { path: ':city/:subscategory', component: ExploreListComponent }, 
      { path: ':city/:subscategory/:singleitem', component: DetailedPageComponent },
    ];
```

**app.component.ts**

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      moduleId: module.id,
      selector: 'my-app',
      template: `
         <app-header></app-header>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        <app-footer></app-footer>
      `, 
    })
    export class AppComponent { }
```

**header.component.ts**

```
    import { Component,Renderer } from '@angular/core';
    import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';

    @Component({
      moduleId: module.id,
      selector: 'app-header',
      template: `header html script`,
    })

    export class HeaderComponent { 
     constructor(title: Title) {  }
    }
```

**footer.component.ts**

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';      

    @Component({
      moduleId: module.id,
      selector: 'app-footer',
      template: `comman footer html script`,

    })
    export class FooterComponent {

    }
```

**index.html**

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
        <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <title></title>
          <base href="/">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
          <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
          <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        </head>
        <body>
           <my-app>Loading...</my-app>     
        </body>
    </html>
```

**homepage.component.ts**

```
  @Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'homepage.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['homepage.component.css'],
    providers: [ CountriesService]
  })

  export class HomepageComponent {  
    ngOnInit() {             
               }        
  }
```

Comment: That should be the default behavior. Please try if this issue gets fixed if you use `imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(myRoutes, {useHash: true})]`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, not working.

Comment: Hard to tell, because this should just work. Can you reproduce in a Plunker?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, see this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/P1jR4cj4m2yiP2NoAHs5?p=preview. There is no error. but page not loading.

Comment: You should start with the Plunker template provided by Plunker `New > Angular`.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, could please check http://plnkr.co/edit/PTnZWf6W3NlMnY3fwSWS?

Comment: It doesn't do anything. You should move the files into the `src` folder. Just double click on the file name and prefix them with `src/`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I have made a basic demo keeping in mind your requirements:

Common header and footer, You can make changes and add APIs in it according to your need.

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

Check out this Plunker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/aMLa3p00sLWka0pn5UNT

Comment: How do I pass parameters from components "below" my root component to the footer and header?

Comment: @Azimuth Could you please elaborate what exactly you want to do ?

Comment: I didn't think it would be this simple! Nice, thanks!

Comment: @aman: sir how to manage via session,we have show different header if user is login and logout case?

Comment: I feel just to show how it is done, the example snippet above is suffice BUT if do consider how you display 404 component/page and especially if your 404 doesn't include header and footer (which is most of the case) then you need to re-think your component architecture

Comment: Is there a way to hide them on certain pages? I have a couple of pages where I don't need a header and footer?

Answer (score 9):

you could use two times in the terminal:

```
ng generate component header
ng generate component footer
```

Then, in the main app file HTML (i.e. `app.component.html`) you must include the 2 tags:

```
<app-header></app-header>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

this is the first thing to do.

Then you must populate your templates:

- `header.component.html` and the styling in `header.component.css`
- `footer.component.html` and the styling in `footer.component.css`

Answer (score 3):

From your description of the current behavior, it sounds like you are using standard html-style links, instead of Angular's RouterLink.

See the documentation at https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterLink-directive.html

Answer (score 0):

In that case replace your code with this :

**Index.html :**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title></title>
      <base href="/">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
      <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
       <app-header></app-header>
       <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
       <app-footer></app-footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      moduleId: module.id,
      selector: 'my-app',
      template: `
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      `, 
    })
    export class AppComponent { }
```

Comment: still working same. header and footer is displaying double times.

Comment: Will you please post HomepageComponent

Comment: using selector: 'my-app', for both component ?

Comment: I used like that. I dont know how to use in homepage?

Comment: I tries with  selector: 'homepage', but no luck

Comment: header and footer not loading in all page

Comment: will you please show also module file ? and please set js fiddle if possible.

Answer (score 0):

this is the way I have followed, you can load all other pages in the router outlet

```
<div id="wrapper" style="height: 100vh;">

<!-- Sidebar -->
<app-sidebar [isToggle]="true"></app-sidebar>
<!-- End of Sidebar -->

<!-- Content Wrapper -->
<div id="content-wrapper" class="d-flex flex-column">
    <!-- Main Content -->
    <div id="content">
        <!-- Topbar -->
        <app-header></app-header>
        <!-- End of Topbar -->
        <!-- Begin Page Content -->
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
        <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </div>
    <!-- End of Main Content -->
    <!-- Footer -->
    <app-footer></app-footer>
    <!-- End of Footer -->
</div>
<!-- End of Content Wrapper -->
```

Comment: question was asked 2 years ago.